# Outputting information to a ListView by passing values from a fragment

Tags: android, sql, mobile, fragment

I have an application that pulls values from the SSMS database. On one fragment, using the List, I create buttons and when I click on a button, I transfer it to another fragment where I want to create dynamically values ​​through the FK that correspond to the request. But it doesn't work

Here are examples of the code I have written.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEZs3.png)
also i have CategoriesAdapter

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Categories> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context, List<Categories> data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_categories_list_item);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Categories category = data.get(position);
        holder.button.setText(category.CategoriesName);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        Button button;
        //TextView textView;
    }
}
```

I also have a LevelsAdapter that passes the value I need

```
public class LevelsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Levels> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public LevelsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Levels> data) {
        this.fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.level_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_list_item);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Levels level = data.get(position);
        // holder.button.setText(level.name);
        holder.button.setText(String.valueOf(level.id));
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Levels level = data.get(position);

                // Создаем новый фрагмент для отображения категорий
                Fragment categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment();

                // Передаем информацию о выбранном уровне во фрагмент
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("selectedLevel", level.id);
                categoriesFragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Frame_Layout, categoriesFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        Button button;
    }
}
```

Values are passed to the desired fragment and set simply in the text field, but the list is not displayed

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Categories> categories;

   private  ListView listView;
    private int selectedLevelId;
    private CategoriesAdapter adaptercategories;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);
        selectedLevelId = getArguments().getInt("selectedLevel");
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_categoriee);


        return view;


    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.testtxtv);
        text.setText("Выбранный уровень: " + selectedLevelId);

        List<Categories> getData = new GetData().getData(selectedLevelId);
        adaptercategories = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), getData);
        listView.setAdapter(adaptercategories);
    }
```